# Validating order of XML elements using XMLUnit

Tags: java, xml, xml-validation, xmlunit

I need to validate order of my output xml against a XSD using XMLUnit framework. I am new to XMLUnit and have no idea how to do it. I know that XMLUnit compares two XMLs but how to compare XML against a XSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using XMLUnit for this aspect, you could use the `javax.xml.validation` APIs that are available in Java SE 5 and above:

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("customer.xsd"));

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
validator.validate(source);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

Comment: I want to use XMLUnit test cases as Unit test cases for my piece of code so that other developers can make sure they are developing XML in a proper way.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav - You can still use XMLUnit for all your other test cases.  Then you can use the Java SE APIs to add an additional test for schema validation.

Comment: Dougham - Thanks for the quick reply. I will try it out with Java SE APIs.

Comment: Dougham I am getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'OLifE'but element is already present in the XSD as <xsd:element name="OLifE" type="OLifE_Type" />
 <xsd:complexType name="OLifE_Type">